# String variable args are treated as dict types in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

```
*** Test Cases ***
Log Test
  Run Keyword LogType

*** Keyword ***
LogType
  ${type_object}= Evaluate  type( ${TC_ARGS} )   
  Log To Console  the type object is ${type_object}
```

When i run this with the command, `pybot -v TC_ARGS:'{"a":"b"}' a.robot`
, robot prints,

```
the type object is <type 'dict'>
```

But, isn't it the default behavior to treat single quoted literals as `strings`? So, ideally it must have printed `<type 'str'>` instead of `<type 'dict'>`.

Comment: I guess the python interpreter can parse arguments and infer their types?

Comment: possibly, you are right.. when i passed `-v TC_ARGS:'abc'`, it throws error saying `variable abc is not defined anywhere`?. So, i think, this problem is seen when we do `evaluate` on a robot string? Python `evaluate` treats robot string as variables.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Try `-v TC_ARGS:'"abc"'`, then it will probably be a string.

Comment: Perhaps this is environmental:  I'm on Win7, Python 2.7.6, Robot 2.8.7 and when I run your test it reports `<type 'str'>`.

Comment: What is the value of `${TC_ARGS}` when printing with Robot?

Comment: @Raceyman, yes my friend who uses windows told me, it returns `<type 'str'>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable is a string. To check it, just try to do a dictionary keyword on it (like "get from dictionary" from [Collections lib)](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html) and you will see it fails.

Run this code to see it:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Log Test
  # let's test a proper dictionary 
  ${dict} =  create dictionary  a  b
  ${value} =  get from dictionary  ${dict}  a
  should be equal  ${value}  b
  log to console  ${\n}this was a real dictionary
  # ${TC_ARGS} is passed on command line
  # evaluate might let us thing we have a dict
  ${type_object} =  Evaluate  type( ${TC_ARGS} )   
  Log To Console  the type object is ${type_object}
  # but in fact this is a string and doing a dict operation will fail
  get from dictionary  ${type_object}  a
```

To understand why you get dict type from evaluate, you have to understand that [evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) is just "evaluating the given expression in Python and returns the results.". So it take its argument as a plain string a launch it with Python like you would do it on Python command line.

Now if you check your argument on Python command line, here is what you get:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 19 2014, 06:00:59)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> type({"a":"b"})
<type 'dict'>
```

Which is totally normal, because the "string" {"a":"b"} is how you declare a dictionary in Python.

So:

- be careful with "evaluate"
- if you need to pass a dictionary from Robot command line, you will pass it as a string, and then [loads it with json Python library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).